# apt system fails due to missing python, but it's there

Tags: apt, python

A failed attempt to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 left me with broken system, hopefuly only at one element- the python is not recognized within the system, although i've patched (symlink) in /usr/bin so "pythin --version" and "which python" works.
But apt fails-

```
xxx@u9e16c415e3b459:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 alacarte : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)    
 ansible : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
           Depends: python:any (>= 2.7~)
 autokey-common : Depends: python (< 2.8)
.................
.................
```

Same as atempt for fix-broken

```
xxxxx@u9e16c415e3b459:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 alacarte : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)    
 ansible : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
           Depends: python:any (>= 2.7~)
.................
.................

xxxxx@u9e16c415e3b459:~$ which python
/usr/bin/python
xxxxx@u9e16c415e3b459:~$ python 
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

any idea how to recover? of course that re-install python fails the same

Comment: Please add `namei /usr/bin/python` and `namei /usr/bin/python3` to your question.

Comment: These packages are from the old install. They require python2 version 2.7. Yours is 3.6. You must downgrade python or replace these versions with the same from 20.04. To me I think you will be better to backup important data and do a clean install because this is a big big mess.